# CloudFlare and socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, cloudflare

I'm using CloudFlare to implement a REST API. I need to add some notifications which are implemented with socket.io on Node.JS.
When socket.io uses a live connection to keep client updated it will work because the connection is established between server-client, but what happens when socket.io does polling? Does CloudFlare use always the same server for each client?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

WebSockets are standardised by the IETF in [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455), this allows you to avoid polling behaviour and instead directly maintain a bi-directional connection from the server to the client.

Whilst your existing stack (Node.js, Socket.io and CloudFlare) support polling behaviour; Socket.io can use WebSockets and [CloudFlare now supports WebSockets](https://blog.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-now-supports-websockets/)!

WebSockets don't use traditional polling and instead act as a full-duplex communication protocol. When it is possible [Socket.io](http://socket.io/get-started/) will [seek to use WebSockets when it can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112178/differences-between-socket-io-and-websockets) but fallback to polling when it can.

So what do you need to bear in mind? When using WebSockets be sure to use Ports that are acceptable to CloudFlare.

```
For requests made via HTTP/WS:

80
8080
8880
2052
2082
2086
2095

For requests made via HTTPS/WSS:

443
2053
2083
2087
2096
8443
```

There is an FAQ for [using CloudFlare with WebSockets](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169466-Can-I-use-CloudFlare-with-WebSockets-).