# Websocket returns 500 on client and 101 on server

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, websocket, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

We try to implement WebSocket on the Kubernetes cluster using nginx-ingress controller.

**ingress.yaml:**

```sh
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "7200"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "7200"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
  generation: 2
  labels:
    app: websocket
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    chart: websocket-0.2.2693
    release: websocket
  name: websocket
  namespace: %NAME_SPACE%
spec:
  rules:
  - host: %HOST_NAME%
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: websocket
          servicePort: 443
        path: /
      - backend:
          serviceName: websocket
          servicePort: 443
        path: /socket.io
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: X.X.X.X
    - ip: Y.Y.Y.Y
```

**service.yaml**

```sh
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: websocket
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: %NAME_SPACE%
  creationTimestamp: "2020-04-27T20:58:28Z"
  labels:
    app: websocket
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    chart: websocket-0.2.2723
    release: websocket
  name: websocket
  namespace: %NAME_SPACE%
  resourceVersion: "2916073"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/%NAME_SPACE%/services/websocket
  uid: e4c08a00-6824-4e16-a3fa-cace0c9be519
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.0.3.45
  ports:
  - name: websocket
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 443
  selector:
    app: websocket
    release: websocket
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

**deployment.yaml:**

```sh
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "16"
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: websocket
  labels:
    app: websocket
    release: websocket
  name: websocket
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 5
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: websocket
      release: websocket
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 0
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        image: %NAME_SPACE%.azurecr.io/websocket:2723
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: websocket
        ports:
        - containerPort: 443
          name: websocket
          protocol: TCP
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 1500m
            memory: 1Gi
          requests:
            cpu: 250m
            memory: 64Mi
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
```

When getting the log from nginx-ingress pod we noticed that the status code is `101` which means it's working.

```sh
kubectl logs %POD_NAME% -n nginx-ingress --since 1m | grep websocket
```

**Output:**

```sh
[11/May/2020:12:47:29 +0000] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket HTTP/1.1" 101 91
```

However, The client return `500` :

```
Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 500
```

And the connection is closed automatically.

I'm familiar with the following threads but none worked for me:

https://gist.github.com/jsdevtom/7045c03c021ce46b08cb3f41db0d76da#file-ingress-service-yaml

https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/3746

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Support for [websockets is provided by NGINX out of the box](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/miscellaneous/#websockets), Which cloud provider are you using? what is the protocol between the LB and NGINX? TCP?

Comment: @willrof - Azure - TCP. Yes, i know WebSocket supported out of the box but none worked for me. looks like the handshake is falling on the client.

Comment: would you try with the image mentioned in [this example](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/1609#issuecomment-340096599) to confirm it's not an issue in the cloud TCP load balancer? I'm thinking on how to reproduce with an HTTPS websocket. Can you provide the deployment/svc yamls for this https socket? It would be very helpful.

Comment: @willrof update my question with the deployment and service

Comment: thank you for the info, but I can't really test it due to your private docker image, I'd like to suggest you to try accessing the service directly via api : `kubectl port-forward -n %NAME_SPACE% service/websocket 7000:443` and inspect the requests in developers tools and take a look on http requests and ws connection because it looks like an https backend issue, please provide the screens from dev console. Also, are you using network loadbalncer (L4)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue was on the Cloudflare side, we test the current solution against a different domain and it's working perfectly.

Few articles and answers that might help:

[cloudflare-and-socket-io](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38704819/9931092)

[Socket.io + nginx + cloudflare problems](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/socket-io-nginx-cloudflare-problems/107450/9)

[Socket.io over https with cloudflare](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/socket-io-over-https-with-cloudflare/76612/25)