# socket.io no communication between server and client

Tags: node.js, express, angular, socket.io

I'm currently trying to have an angular2 frontend communicating with a node.js backend with socket.io.
The point is, I get the client connected to the server, but after that, no socket call can be successfully passed between them.
Here is a simple piece a code for the server :

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

io.on('connection', function() {
    io.emit('update');
    console.log('Connected');
});
io.on('updated', function() {
    io.emit('update');
    console.log('Updated');
});

server.listen(5000, function() {
    console.log('Listening on 5000');
});
```

... and for the component :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import * as io from 'socket.io-client';

@Component({
  selector: 'main-app',
  template: `
  <div>
  <button (click)="foo()"
           style='padding:20px; background:red; color:white'>
    click me
  </button>
  </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'bar';
  socket = null;

  constructor() {
    let self = this;
      self.socket = io.connect('http://mysuperwebsite:5000', {
          transports : ["websocket"]
      });
      self.socket.on('update', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      });
  }

  foo() {
    let self = this;
    self.socket.emit('updated', {});
  }
}
```

I can't get what is wrong, I guess you will ;)
Thanks for your help !

EDIT : Finally, the problem seemed to come from the lack of second parameter in io.emit(). Now it works, thanks you very much :)

Comment: Did any of the answers below help you find your problem? If so then you may consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) because right now other people searching for this problem see that your question has no good answer and may not read it. If not then you should comment on them so that they could be improved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of debugging your code, I'll post you an example that works and you can go from there:

### Socket.IO Server

Socket.IO server example using Express.js:

```
var path = require('path');
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.error('express connection');
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'si.html'));
});
io.on('connection', s => {
  console.error('socket.io connection');
  for (var t = 0; t < 3; t++)
    setTimeout(() => s.emit('message', 'message from server'), 1000*t);
});
http.listen(3002, () => console.error('listening on http://localhost:3002/'));
console.error('socket.io example');
```

Source: https://github.com/rsp/node-websocket-vs-socket.io/blob/master/si.js

### Socket.IO Client

Socket.IO client example using vanilla JavaScript:

```
var l = document.getElementById('l');
var log = function (m) {
    var i = document.createElement('li');
    i.innerText = new Date().toISOString()+' '+m;
    l.appendChild(i);
}
log('opening socket.io connection');
var s = io();
s.on('connect_error', function (m) { log("error"); });
s.on('connect', function (m) { log("socket.io connection open"); });
s.on('message', function (m) { log(m); });
```

Source: https://github.com/rsp/node-websocket-vs-socket.io/blob/master/si.html

That example can be [installed from npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket-vs-socket.io) or [downloaded from GitHub](https://github.com/rsp/node-websocket-vs-socket.io). It's as simple as it gets and it's known to work so you can have a working backend part to test your frontend with.

It was written for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112178/differences-between-socket-io-and-websockets/38558531#38558531) - you can find mush more info there.

Answer (score 0):

Your server setup seems to be incorrect.

Try this:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.emit('update');
  console.log('Connected');
  socket.on('updated', function() {
    socket.emit('update');
    console.log('Updated');
  });
});
```