# getting an error when trying to use socket.io

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, swift, sockets

I am currently working with socket.io swift client. Running on Iphone SE. this is the swift code

```
 let socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: URL(string: "http://example.com:4000")!, config: [.log(true), .forcePolling(true)]);
        socket.connect();
        socket.on("connect") {data, ack in
            print("socket is connected");
            socket.emit("getData", ["data": 3]);
        }
```

And on the server:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });
    socket.on('getData', function(result){
        console.log(result);
    });
});


app.listen(4000, function () {
  console.log(' on at 4000!');
});
```

...And on the Xcode console, I get

```
2016-09-29 16:38:33.871895 proj[3070:1019256] LOG SocketEngine: Handshaking
2016-09-29 16:38:33.872301 proj[3070:1019256] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Doing polling request
2016-09-29 16:38:34.004312 proj[3070:1019256] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Got polling response
2016-09-29 16:38:34.004874 proj[3070:1019283] LOG SocketEngine: Got message: Cannot GET /socket.io/?transport=polling&amp;b64=1
2016-09-29 16:38:34.005283 proj[3070:1019283] ERROR SocketIOClient: Got unknown error from server Cannot GET /socket.io/?transport=polling&amp;b64=1
```

Which demonstrates a connection is made and the server is successfully found, but something else is wrong.
Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Sidenote: If you don't need support for old browsers (or any browsers for that matter, since your client is a native mobile app) then you may consider using WebSocket which is an open standard. Socket.io is usually used to have a WebSocket-like functionality on browsers that don't support WebSocket. WebSocket on the other hand is an open standard, has a wide support (not only in browsers) and it has a better performance. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112178/differences-between-socket-io-and-websockets/38558531#38558531) for more details.)

Now, since you are already using **Socket.io** then here is how you can diagnose the problem. I would try to connect from a browser, which is a main way to connect with Socket.io, and see if that works. If it doesn't then it would mean that there's a problem in your server code. If it does then it could mean that there's a problem in your client. That would be the first thing to check. Going from there you can narrow the problem and hopefully fix it.

If you want to have a starting point with some working code using Socket.io, both server-site (Node.js) and client-side (browser vanilla JavaScript), then you can see the examples that I wrote originally for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112178/differences-between-socket-io-and-websockets/38558531#38558531), that are available [on GitHub](https://github.com/rsp/node-websocket-vs-socket.io) and [on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket-vs-socket.io):

### Socket.IO Server

Socket.IO server example using Express.js:

```
var path = require('path');
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.error('express connection');
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'si.html'));
});
io.on('connection', s => {
  console.error('socket.io connection');
  for (var t = 0; t < 3; t++)
    setTimeout(() => s.emit('message', 'message from server'), 1000*t);
});
http.listen(3002, () => console.error('listening on http://localhost:3002/'));
console.error('socket.io example');
```

Source: https://github.com/rsp/node-websocket-vs-socket.io/blob/master/si.js

### Socket.IO Client

Socket.IO client example using vanilla JavaScript:

```
var l = document.getElementById('l');
var log = function (m) {
    var i = document.createElement('li');
    i.innerText = new Date().toISOString()+' '+m;
    l.appendChild(i);
}
log('opening socket.io connection');
var s = io();
s.on('connect_error', function (m) { log("error"); });
s.on('connect', function (m) { log("socket.io connection open"); });
s.on('message', function (m) { log(m); });
```

Source: https://github.com/rsp/node-websocket-vs-socket.io/blob/master/si.html

You can compare the same code with WebSocket versions:

### WebSocket Server

WebSocket server example using Express.js:

```
var path = require('path');
var app = require('express')();
var ws = require('express-ws')(app);
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.error('express connection');
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'ws.html'));
});
app.ws('/', (s, req) => {
  console.error('websocket connection');
  for (var t = 0; t < 3; t++)
    setTimeout(() => s.send('message from server', ()=>{}), 1000*t);
});
app.listen(3001, () => console.error('listening on http://localhost:3001/'));
console.error('websocket example');
```

Source: https://github.com/rsp/node-websocket-vs-socket.io/blob/master/ws.js

### WebSocket Client

WebSocket client example using vanilla JavaScript:

```
var l = document.getElementById('l');
var log = function (m) {
    var i = document.createElement('li');
    i.innerText = new Date().toISOString()+' '+m;
    l.appendChild(i);
}
log('opening websocket connection');
var s = new WebSocket('ws://'+window.location.host+'/');
s.addEventListener('error', function (m) { log("error"); });
s.addEventListener('open', function (m) { log("websocket connection open"); });
s.addEventListener('message', function (m) { log(m.data); });
```

Source: https://github.com/rsp/node-websocket-vs-socket.io/blob/master/ws.html

I hope this can help you evaluate whether staying with Socket.io or going with WebSocket is the right decision for you, and will give you some working client-side code to test your backend. The code is [released under the MIT license](https://github.com/rsp/node-websocket-vs-socket.io#license) (open source, free software) so feel free to use it in your project.

Comment: Which browsers does websocket not support? It sounds much better actually. Can you point me in the direction of it's swift client? I think I might not even bother staying with socket.io then based on what ive now read. Really appreciate the in depth answer.

Comment: @harrylakins Last time I've done some research when explaining some misconceptions about websocket vs socket.io in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112178/differences-between-socket-io-and-websockets/38558531#38558531) the only browser not supporting websocket was opera mini. See http://caniuse.com/websockets for up-to-date info.

Comment: Ah thats much better than it could have been. Any ideas about a swift client ?

Comment: Hey @rsp I've read a few of your SO answers and checked out your repo. Well done.

I was wondering with the extra stuff socket.io has, like: Making connections through firewall & antivirus software. And Auto reconnection. And also using forced websockets via transports, would it be better or does socket.io still fall short? (Use case: realtime game)