# Npm test cannot find socket.io.js file

Tags: node.js, angular, testing, npm

I am trying to make tests using Karma and i am following Angulars own testing guide. Currently i am using the most basic test class but having issues running it.

The test class:

```
describe('1st test',()=>{
it('true is true', ()=> expect(true).toBe(true)); });
```

When i run it using npm test i get the following error in the command prompt:

```
 [1] 24 04 2017 11:27:24.957:WARN [web-server]: 404: /base/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js
[1] Chrome 57.0.2987 (Windows 10 0.0.0) ERROR
[1]   {
[1]     "__zone_symbol__error": {
[1]       "originalStack": "Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js\n\tError: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js\n\tError loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js as \"socket.io-client\" from src/app/global/socket.service.js",
[1]       "zoneAwareStack": "Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js\n\tError: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js\n\tError loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js as \"socket.io-client\" from src/app/global/socket.service.js"
[1]     },
[1]     "stack": "(SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js\n\tError: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js\n\tError loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js as \"socket.io-client\" from src/app/global/socket.service.js",
[1]     "name": "Error",
[1]     "message": "(SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js\n\tError: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js\n\tError loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js as \"socket.io-client\" from src/app/global/socket.service.js",
[1]     "originalStack": "Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js\n\tError: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js\n\tError loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js as \"socket.io-client\" from src/app/global/socket.service.js",
[1]     "zoneAwareStack": "Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js\n\tError: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js\n\tError loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js as \"socket.io-client\" from src/app/global/socket.service.js",
[1]     "__zone_symbol__stack": "(SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js\n\tError: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js\n\tError loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js as \"socket.io-client\" from src/app/global/socket.service.js",
[1]     "originalErr": {
[1]       "__zone_symbol__error": {
[1]         "originalStack": "Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js",
[1]         "zoneAwareStack": "Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js"
[1]       },
[1]       "stack": "Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js",
[1]       "name": "Error",
[1]       "message": "XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js",
[1]       "originalStack": "Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js",
[1]       "zoneAwareStack": "Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js",
[1]       "__zone_symbol__currentTask": {
[1]         "type": "microTask",
[1]         "state": "notScheduled",
[1]         "source": "Promise.then",
[1]         "zone": "<root>",
[1]         "cancelFn": null,
[1]         "runCount": 0
[1]       },
[1]       "__zone_symbol__stack": "Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js",
[1]       "__zone_symbol__message": "XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js",
[1]       "__zone_symbol__name": "Error",
[1]       "__zone_symbol__originalStack": "Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js",
[1]       "__zone_symbol__zoneAwareStack": "Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js"
[1]     },
[1]     "__zone_symbol__currentTask": {
[1]       "type": "microTask",
[1]       "state": "notScheduled",
[1]       "source": "Promise.then",
[1]       "zone": "<root>",
[1]       "cancelFn": null,
[1]       "runCount": 0
[1]     },
[1]     "__zone_symbol__name": "Error",
[1]     "__zone_symbol__message": "(SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js\n\tError: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js\n\tError loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js as \"socket.io-client\" from src/app/global/socket.service.js",
[1]     "__zone_symbol__originalStack": "Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js\n\tError: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js\n\tError loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js as \"socket.io-client\" from src/app/global/socket.service.js",
[1]     "__zone_symbol__zoneAwareStack": "Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js\n\tError: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js\n\tError loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js as \"socket.io-client\" from src/app/global/socket.service.js"
[1]   }
[1]
[1] Chrome 57.0.2987 (Windows 10 0.0.0) ERROR
[1]   {
[1]     "__zone_symbol__error": {
[1]       "originalStack": "Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js\n\tError: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js\n\tError loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js as \"socket.io-client\" from src/app/global/socket.service.js",
[1]       "zoneAwareStack": "Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js\n\tError: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js\n\tError loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js as \"socket.io-client\" from src/app/global/socket.service.js"
[1]     },
[1]     "stack": "(SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js\n\tError: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js\n\tError loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js as \"socket.io-client\" from src/app/global/socket.service.js",
[1]     "name": "Error",
[1]     "message": "(SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js\n\tError: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js\n\tError loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js as \"socket.io-client\" from src/app/global/socket.service.js",
[1]     "originalStack": "Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js\n\tError: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js\n\tError loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js as \"socket.io-client\" from src/app/global/socket.service.js",
[1]     "zoneAwareStack": "Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js\n\tError: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js\n\tError loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js as \"socket.io-client\" from src/app/global/socket.service.js",
[1]     "__zone_symbol__stack": "(SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js\n\tError: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js\n\tError loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js as \"socket.io-client\" from src/app/global/socket.service.js",
[1]     "originalErr": {
[1]       "__zone_symbol__error": {
[1]         "originalStack": "Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js",
[1]         "zoneAwareStack": "Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js"
[1]       },
[1]       "stack": "Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js",
[1]       "name": "Error",
[1]       "message": "XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js",
[1]       "originalStack": "Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js",
[1]       "zoneAwareStack": "Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js",
[1]       "__zone_symbol__currentTask": {
[1]         "type": "microTask",
[1]         "state": "notScheduled",
[1]         "source": "Promise.then",
[1]         "zone": "<root>",
[1]         "cancelFn": null,
[1]         "runCount": 0
[1]       },
[1]       "__zone_symbol__stack": "Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js",
[1]       "__zone_symbol__message": "XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js",
[1]       "__zone_symbol__name": "Error",
[1]       "__zone_symbol__originalStack": "Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js",
[1]       "__zone_symbol__zoneAwareStack": "Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js"
[1]     },
[1]     "__zone_symbol__currentTask": {
[1]       "type": "microTask",
[1]       "state": "notScheduled",
[1]       "source": "Promise.then",
[1]       "zone": "<root>",
[1]       "cancelFn": null,
[1]       "runCount": 0
[1]     },
[1]     "__zone_symbol__name": "Error",
[1]     "__zone_symbol__message": "(SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js\n\tError: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js\n\tError loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js as \"socket.io-client\" from src/app/global/socket.service.js",
[1]     "__zone_symbol__originalStack": "Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js\n\tError: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js\n\tError loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js as \"socket.io-client\" from src/app/global/socket.service.js",
[1]     "__zone_symbol__zoneAwareStack": "Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js\n\tError: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js\n\tError loading src/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js as \"socket.io-client\" from src/app/global/socket.service.js"
[1]   }
```

I have checked the file that it cannot find and it exists in the directory stated by the error so i have no clue what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Those are 404 errors for XHR requests. It doesn't mean that the file does not exist in the file system but that it is not served by accessing that particular path. It is unlikely that your server serves the entire file system so you shouldn't be worried if the file exists there or not but if it is being served from a particular URL that your program is trying to access it from.

See the code examples in this answer for an example:

- [Getting data from/writing data to localhost with Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43499382/getting-data-from-writing-data-to-localhost-with-express/43500104#43500104)

Here the `socket.io.js` file is referenced in HTML as:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

not as an absolute path in the file system, and not with a path including `node_modules`. Paths in the HTTP requests and paths in the file system are a different thing and 404 errors are HTTP-specific.

Comment: But how do i fix this error for me? I'm really clueless of what to change and where.