# The script doesn't work after deploying a javascript app to heroku

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, animation, heroku

I created a simple javascript app with mojs, an animation library, and wanted to deploy it to heroku. First, I tried to "heroku create" etc and deploy the original app to heroku - the app was accessible, but the script didn't work. Second, I tried to change an app that I made following the Node.js tutorial from heroku website, by inserting a script bootstrap tag

```
   <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/mojs/latest/mo.min.js"></script>
   <script src="myburstscript.js"></script>
```

copying the script I made to the folder of this app

```
var myBurst = new mojs.Burst({

    count:10, 
    radius: {0 :150},
    angle: {0 : 180},
    children : {
      //fill:{'red' : 'blue'},
      fill: ['red', 'purple', 'blue', 'violet'],
      duration : 1000, 
      radius: 10,
      shape: 'polygon',
      delay: 'stagger(50)'
}

});

document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
   myBurst.replay();

 });
```

then running "npm install mojs", and, as usual,

```
 git add .
 git commit -m "somedumbsh*t"
 git push heroku master
```

But it didn't play the animation it plays on my localhost. Logs show no errors. The rest, the html part of the page, works fine. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Heroku needs some server, not only the client-side code.

If you cannot start your app with:

```
PORT=4446 npm start
```

and then access it on:

- http://localhost:4446/

then you won't be able to host it on Heroku.
(I'm assuming that you're using Node as indicated by the tags in your question.) It's important that your app needs to actually use the port number provided in the `PORT` environment variable, not just a hardcoded port number.

For example if you put all your static files (HTML, client-site JavaScript, CSS, images etc.) in a directory called `html` then you can use a simple server like this, e.g. called `server.js`:

```
'use strict';

const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT || 3338;

app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'html')));

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on http://localhost:${port}/`));
```

Example `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "your-name",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Your description",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
  },
  "author": "Your details",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.15.2",
  }
}
```

See also this example that I posted on GitHub for a complete solution that even has a Deploy to Heroku button:

- https://github.com/rsp/node-live-color

It is an example that was created for this answer:

- [Getting data from/writing data to localhost with Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43499382/getting-data-from-writing-data-to-localhost-with-express/43500104#43500104)

where you can find more details on why it was written like that.

Comment: I can access it and I can deploy it. The only problem is that my mojs script doesn't run

Comment: @NiHao92 "script doesn't run" is not enough for anyone to tell you what's wrong. Is the HTML page loaded? Are there any errors in the console? Are there any failed requests in the network connections? Is mo.min.js loaded? Is myburstscript.js loaded? Does myburstscript.js as served from heroku contain exactly what it should? Does it have correct content type? Are there no CORS problems? Simple "doesn't run" means nothing, really. You need to properly investigate it if you expect anyone to help you.

Comment: logs show no errors. The html pages loads normally. As for other questions in your reply -  how to figure that out?