# How to make a nodejs script be a CLI tool in linux?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unix

I made a javascript file `mytool.js`, it has some dependencies (in package.json).

Now I can execute typing in

```
~/mynodes/mytool $ node mytool
```

But if I change the working directory I can't use this command anymore because previously it was run locally.
What I want to achieve is to be able to just type :

```
~$ mytool
```

(wherever I am in my system's filesystem and without typing `node` before).

> Should I install it manually ?

If yes, where is the common location to install a personal nodejs script in a unix-like system ?

> Or is there a npm-like command to install a personal script system
>   wide ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add a "bin" key in your package.json:

```
  "bin": {
    "mytool": "mytool.js"
  },
```

then you will be able to install your script with `npm install -g` and it will be automatically added where it should be (to a place where other globally installed cli tools are installed, which should be in your PATH).

You can see this simple project as an example:

- https://github.com/rsp/node-websocket-vs-socket.io

It was created as an example for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112178/differences-between-socket-io-and-websockets/38558531#38558531) but it does what you need:

1. it has a single script to run
2. it has external dependencies
3. it can be installed globally
4. it can be run from any place with a single command

Note that you don't need to publish your script to npm to be able to install it - though you can do it, or you can also install projects directly from GitHub (including private repos) - but you can also install a module that you have in your local directory or a tarball:

```
npm install -g module-on-npm
npm install -g user/repo-on-github
npm install -g /your/local/directory
npm install -g /your/local/tarball.tgz
```

For more options, see:

- https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

Also keep in mind that for your program to be able to be executed from anywhere, you need to use paths relative to `__dirname` or `__filename` if you need to access your own files relative to your code. See:

- https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_dirname

Answer (score 1):

1. Put a shebang line at the top of the script (e.g. `#!/usr/bin/env node`).
2. Put the script in a directory in your `$PATH`
3. Give it executable permission (e.g. `chmod +x /usr/local/bin/example.js`)

Comment: I like the idea so I upvoted but the problem is I have to manually install the dependencies the same way which is not really convenient.

Answer (score 1):

First option:

You can run your file globally by putting on the first line of the file : `#!/usr/bin/env node`, copying it to `/usr/local/bin` and make it executable: `sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/yourfile.js` and then you can call it from where you want with `yourfile.js`

Second option:

Make your local file executable and create an executable bash script which calls your local file and put it in `/usr/local/bin` and then call the bashfile globally.

Comment: This will work but I would recommend putting your own files to /usr/local/bin if you need to instead of /usr/bin which is usually managed by the package manager of the OS.

Comment: @rsp I think `/usr/bin` is fine, I tried what you suggested and `npm install -g` will install the package in that directory.

Comment: If you have dependencies in the local folder you should definetely try my second method and creating a bash script in `/usr/bin` or `usr/local/bin` and from there call your file by its absolute path.

Comment: @AlexLucaci I like your second option too, but I will use rsp's solution. I don't know why but it is more trustful to use the `npm install` command.

Comment: @ballangddang whatever suits your need :D