# Is it possible to find out data in websocket using browser

Tags: browser, websocket

I saw somewhere about some extension, may be only for Chrome, that could reveal data that goes through websocket but I can't find where I read it or possibly I've misunderstand those info. Is there are any way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to view WS/WSS Websocket request content using Firebug or other?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9221018/how-to-view-ws-wss-websocket-request-content-using-firebug-or-other)

Comment: As described in the duplicate, the Chrome debugger can show webSocket traffic.