# Debugging binary websockets frames

Tags: browser, websocket, browser-extension

Packet analyzers like [Wireshark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751495/debugging-websocket-in-google-chrome), and [Fiddler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9221018/how-to-view-ws-wss-websocket-request-content-using-firebug-or-other) allows for low-level packet dump, and appears to be the recommended way to debug binary websocket frames. Major problems of this approach includes secure websocket layers, complexity, friction in the development process, amongst others.

Other than Wireshark, what **browser native, or extension tools** are available to see at least a hex dump of binary frames exchanged via Websockets?

*edit: as of Chrome 56.0, only frames of textual websocket connections can be watched (by going debug console (F12) -> Network -> Selecting the websocket connection (to identify: it has 101 HTTP status code) -> Frames panel); binary packets still show up as "binary frame (Opcode 2)*

Comment: As @MrCC has correctly pointed out (in a now-deleted answer's comment), that nope, Chrome still doesn't do binary packets

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox you use [Web Socket Monitor](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/websocket-monitor/) extension to get hex dump for binary packets.

[image: Example of web socket monition]

Comment: It's deprecated since Firefox Quantum (FF 57)

Comment: any other alternative?

Comment: The link has gone stale.