# How to inspect WebSocket frames in Chrome properly?

Tags: websocket, google-chrome-devtools

I've entered [echo.websocket.org](http://websocket.org/echo.html) as it was suggested, opened Network tab and WS filter in Chrome Developer Tools, but I do not see any frames. I see connection entries, but Frames tab always stays empty. Is there anything special I should do to see the frames?

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Just tested here and I can see the frames properly. Could you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Updated with the screenshot.

Comment: I guess they should put some minimal height on that section.

Comment: Yeah, they should...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As of December 10, 2019, the process is slightly different to debug WebSockets with Chrome.

1. Open Chrome **Developer Tools**.
2. Click on the **Network** tab.
3. Click on the filter **WS** (for WebSockets).
4. Reload the page to make sure you see your connection in the **Name** column.
5. Click on **Messages**.

Now you should see all your communications with your WebSockets, with 3 columns: Data, Length and Time.

[image: Chrome DevTools WebSockets]

Comment: Hi [Armel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7810468/armel) and thanks for your answer! I was wondering what the arrows stand for, I can also see a black arrow next to one of the my WS messages

Comment: This is the correct answer, other replies are out of date. I am using Chrome 105.0.0.0

Comment: How does chrome websocket monitor filter message by keyword?

Answer (score 83):

Click **Network**, **WS**, select the original HTTP connection and then click the **Frames** tab. Be aware that the content of this tab may be *hidden* by another pane, so you need to drag the bar down to see the WebSocket frames.

[image]

Comment: Same here! Don't event know how that happened and it is not obvious at first. Thank-you

Comment: Hi @[cassiomolin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1426227/cassiomolin) and thanks for your answer! I was wondering what the arrows stand for, I can also see a black arrow next to one of the my WS messages

Comment: I wish there was a way to get this info out of here and into Excel. I want to analyze times & sizes.

Comment: @RyanShillington Perhaps this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29953531/1426227 And you may try a HAR analysers tool: https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/har_analyzer/

Comment: @cassiomolin Thanks! My client sent me the har file, so I can't easily reproduce it. The har_analyzer doesn't help at all, unfortunately.

Comment: @ChagaiFriedlander the green upward arrows are for messages which are sent and red downward arrows for messages that are received. There is also a dropdown in the toolbar to  filter the messages based on direction.

Comment: How does chrome websocket monitor filter message by keyword?

Answer (score 20):

Did you send any data on the page? You need to try sending a message after clicking `Connect`:

[image: Sockets]

There is also a useful area in Chrome where you can view all your active sockets:

[image: Sockets]

You can access it at here: [chrome://net-internals/#events&q=type:SOCKET%20is:active](http://chrome://net-internals/#events&q=type:SOCKET%20is:active)

**Update:**

After seeing your newly added screenshot, it looks like your Data table is squashed up and you need to drag it down to see the entries.

Comment: I also had a squashed up data table. Thanks! :)

Comment: Alas chrome://net-internals no longer exists in current versions of Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Another gotcha is that in the new Edge the Developer Tools menu option and the Network/WS display looks very similar to Chrome.  I forgot I was using Edge and spent 20 minutes trying to find the JSON messages, which I don't think are available in Edge.

Comment: Latest Edge is basically Chrome.

Comment: The Messages table in the Chromium Edge 103.0.1264.71 Developer Tools for a web socket may appear empty depending on the size of the tool's window, only showing a horizontal scroll bar and the "Select message to browse its content." window taking all the space. Pull the bottom of the scroll bar to see the messages. Google Chrome Canary 106.0.5202.2 shows at lease a one message.

Comment: How does chrome websocket monitor filter message by keyword?

Answer (score 1):

There's another way you can have a problem here - if you are using livereload in your development flow.

This (apparently, for me at least) causes multiple instances of the socked to appear, all with empty messages.

[image]

[image]

It turns out that only the first one is the "real" one, and has messages:

[image]