# thingsboard widget graph unable to show data beyond 6-7hours

Tags: iot, thingsboard

i've created a custom widget on thingsboard but it's unable to show data beyond 6-7hours. Refer screenshot below.

Tried searching the postgre db tables but unsure where the device telemetry data are stored.. perhaps there is a data capped somewhere..

Any advise please?

Thanks!

screenshot of widget:
[image: screenshot of widget]

Comment: What aggregation type is selected in the widget time window (none, avg, sum)? Please also open browser console and share what command is sent for loading data and what is the response (if data is loaded via WebSocket - you will need to open browser console, refresh the page and filter network requests by WebSockets)

Comment: @VitaliyParomskiy thanks for your reply

the Data Agrgregation function is set to "none".
i'm sending data from sensors to thingsboard via mqtt. May i know where is this browser console do you refer to?

Comment: When aggregation type is 'NONE' - you need to set 'Max Values' property - it is a max number of data points that are returned for the selected time interval. I think that in your case you are reaching the 'Max values' limit. Also Note that in most cases, when you show data on a chart, you do not need to disable aggregation. Thingsboard knows how to correctly aggregated values for different time intervals.

Comment: Also The current limit of max aggregation points has a reason: if you want to display data in a chart on standard screen, with resolution is 1920x1200 pixels - each point will consume ~4 pixels. For human it is really hard to analyze charts with such a lot of points. For example, please open our live demo and configure time window for showing max allowed aggregation point and you will see that it is really hard to detect patterns on the chart. It will be not user-friendly.

Comment: Browser console - if you are using chrome - just press F12. More details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43081107/how-do-you-inspect-websocket-traffic-with-chrome-developer-tools

Comment: @VitaliyParomskiy Yes! i adjusted the "Max Values" Property to max and i do see now the widget graph displaying data up to 12hours but not when i select 1 day. 
To display data for 1 day and more, i would need to set the aggregation type, are you able to advise the reason? thanks alot for your help

Comment: @VitaliyParomskiy noted your comment on the max aggregation points

Answer (score 0):

Go to ThingsBoard database on postgres.
Check tables ts_kv and ts_kv_latest you will see your data.