# Chrome Dev Tools Network can't detect WebSocket?

Tags: networking, websocket, google-chrome-devtools

I was searching about how to implement the awwapp whiteboard service. It is a whiteboard service that users can collaborate in the shared whiteboard. I just thought that it used WebSocket for real-time collaboration. So I inspected the network in https://awwapp.com/ whiteboard. But I can't see any network activities in the chrome dev tools network. It is a bug in Chrome Dev Tools?. Or WebSocket can't be detected in Chrome Dev Tools?
I am looking forward to hearing from StackOverflow community.❤

Comment: [How do you inspect websocket traffic with Chrome Developer Tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43081108)

Comment: thanks, @wOxxOm I just understood.