# network tab in chrome doesnt update for every request sent

Tags: ajax, networking, chromium

so for instance, this is difficult to explain but i will try to my best ability.
if you refresh a page on for instance a discord channel, an ajax request is sent to:
`https://discord.com/api/v8/channels/channelidhere/messages?limit=50`
which gets the last 50 messages sent in the channel. now, interestingly enough, if youre in a channel with lots of new messages being sent the netwrok tab does not update as if there were no requests associated with the channel messages being updated. ive seen this happen with other sites in similar ways and im just curious as to what i may be missing, is there some reason a request would be sent that the network tab doesnt catch? ps: even if i go to the all tab which supposedly captures all requests still no bueno.

Answer (score 0):

It's common that chat website use websockets instead of http to communicate.

maybe this will help you [How do you inspect websocket traffic with Chrome Developer Tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43081107/how-do-you-inspect-websocket-traffic-with-chrome-developer-tools)

Comment: it doesnt seem like websockets update during this procedure either and why would there be a feature over get to retrieve the last 50 messages if this is handled over websockets? youre probably right im not incredibly experienced with javascript just yet. ill have to look into websockets more.