# Callback for WebSocket.prototype.send

Tags: javascript, websocket

I’m trying to monitor how many bytes are received and sent in a WebSocket connection. I can easily count the received bytes in the `"message"` listener. However, I don’t know what’s a proper way to count the sent bytes.

If I do

```
webSocket.send(data);
bytesSent += data.length;
```

then it is not guaranteed that `sentBytes` is not lying. That’s because [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket/send), the `send()` method only enqueues the data, and it doesn’t necessarily mean that the data was sent over the network once it returns.

I have also thought of doing

```
webSocket.send(data);
while (webSocket.bufferedAmount > 0) {
  await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 1));
}
bytesSent += data.length;
```

but it doesn’t seem like a smart way, and it might impact performance.

Do you have any suggestions, or is this even possible given the WebSocket API as it is right now?

Comment: Can't you just monitor the websocket traffic with [the developer tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43081107/how-do-you-inspect-websocket-traffic-with-chrome-developer-tools)? It pretty clearly lists out the size of data sent and received in each message.

Comment: I need to be able to show this to the user. I also need to do the same on Deno, not just browsers.

Comment: Just keep counting `bytesSent` and always display (or "monitor", or whatever you want do with it) the value of `bytesSent - webSocket.bufferedAmount`

Comment: @Bergi Thank you for the suggestion, I’ll be trying it and getting back to you. Should I also reassign `bytesSent` to `bytesSent - webSocket.bufferedAmount` when the connection is closed?

Comment: @Roj No. `bufferedAmount`: "*This value does not reset to zero when the connection is closed*"

Comment: @Bergi hmm, and that’s what I expect it to be I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Keep the total amount of data sent (or: queued, i.e. passed to `send()`) and subtract the [`bufferedAmount`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket/bufferedAmount) at any time from that to get the amount of bytes actually flushed onto the wire.

```
const webSocket = new WebSocket(…);
let bytesSent = 0;

function send(data) {
    const bufferedBefore = webSocket.bufferedAmount;
    webSocket.send(data);
    const bufferedAfter = webSocket.bufferedAmount;
    const size = bufferedAfter - bufferedBefore; // roughly data.length, but with string encoding
    bytesSent += size;
    report();
}

let lastReported = bytesSent;
let timer = 0;
function report() {
    const bytesActuallySent = bytesSent - webSocket.bufferedAmount;
    if (bytesActuallySent != lastReported) {
        console.log(`sent ${bytesActuallySent}`); // or whatever
        lastReported = bytesActuallySent;
    }
    if (timer) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = 0;
    }
    if (webSocket.bufferedAmount > 0) {
        timer = setTimeout(report, 100); // or however fast you need this to update
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Forgot to tell you that I actually store the `bytesSent` in a persistent storage, so I should also store the last `bufferedAmount` along with `bytesSent` to be able to compute the result later on, right? Also, should I reassign `bytesSent` to `bytesSent - webSocket.bufferedAmount` when the connection is closed to be able to merge it with other connections made in the future?

Comment: @Roj I still don't know what your overall goal is, or how that would be achieved when working with multiple connections or connections that are closed before all data is sent. The code in my answer works only for a single websocket. Unless you persist and reopen the connection, you probably should not try to persist the `bytesSent` either. At best, I would persist the `bytesActuallySent`, but really if you want to know how much data has already reached the server, you absolutely should ask the server, it is the sole authority.