# Unable to See Network Call of firebase when using database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

why we are unable to see network call of a firebase in chrome network tab during database call we only see authentication HTTP call but database calls are not seen in the network tab.

Answer (score 4):

Firebase is using websockets and **not HTTP requests** for transfering data. This is the key to its ability to notify the web client of new data in the cloud.

As for monitoring the data on websockets you might find this answer helpful: [How to inspect WebSocket frames in Chrome properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37413092/how-to-inspect-websocket-frames-in-chrome-properly)