# how to view websocket ping and pong frame in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, websocket

In the same site, I can see ping and pong frame in Safari, like picture below:
[image]

but i can't see ping and pong frame in Chrome, the Chrome just include the message i send or receive but not include frame.

[image]

Environment: Chrome version 85.0.4183.121, macOS

Comment: Please check this quetion. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37413092/how-to-inspect-websocket-frames-in-chrome-properly

Comment: @TopTalent thanks, i have checked this question. but i think its not what i want.
i can see data i send or receive, but the "ping" and "pong" frames i can't see.

Comment: Chrome is sending PONG but not showing that in the dev console.

Comment: How can I be sure that ping and pong are transferring between the client and server?

Comment: i've encountered the same issue. Have you found out the reason?

Comment: did you figure out this issue?