# How Facebook hide chat message from xhr response data?

Tags: javascript, facebook, sockets, web, xmlhttprequest

i inspect the network requests and xhr requests for Facebook while chatting  i tried to view the response of this requests but i can't see any message
how Facebook hide this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to inspect WebSocket frames in Chrome properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37413092/how-to-inspect-websocket-frames-in-chrome-properly)

Comment: View websocket messages in Chrome DevTools: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-74/#binary

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

When using sockets requests won't show up in the terminal, since the connection is only established once. After that the connection stays open to send and receive events like a send or receive message. Since no new connections are created or closed there wont be any logs in the terminal. You might see a `switch protocol` request when reloading the page at the beginning.