# WireShark: Secure websockets?

Tags: websocket, wireshark

I'm trying to monitor traffic from secure websocket `wss` on a remote host (I'm using Chrome to connect to it).

I know websocket traffic can be monitored with Chrome DevTools and it works great. But majority of the communication is going on as "Binary Data OPCode 2" over that websocket so people suggested to sniff the traffic with wireshark. But I cannot get it to work.

Also I doubt that I'll be able to read plaintext with wireshark as websocket is over https and is using wss. Is there any way to achieve what I'm primarily trying to do? (Read binary data over secured websockets)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35294463/monitoring-secure-web-sockets-wss-with-wireshark

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Monitoring secure web sockets (wss) with wireshark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35294463/monitoring-secure-web-sockets-wss-with-wireshark)