# websocket constantly disconnecting

Tags: html, websocket

I've been trying to make a websocket chat room that runs in-browser. I've done a bit of googling around and have found a website that provides an example websocket connection (www.websocket.org/echo.html). But whenever I try their "connect" button, it says "disconnected" straight away, and I cannot send a message (this only occurs on Chrome). So I tried it on Firefox, and it says "Error: undefined" and then "disconnected". Both browsers support websocket technology.

So I went to another website (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_websocket.htm) and copied there example code, saved it as ".html" and ran it in chrome. It cannot connect to the websocket. Instead, it says "disconnected".

QUESTION: Why can I not connect to a websocket/why does it keep disconnecting? My Chrome version is 21.0.1180.60.

For further reference, here is my code so far (NOTE: This only is supposed to connect and say that it has connected, not actually chat):

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<title>Testing</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function confirm() {
    if ("WebSocket" in window) {
        alert("WebSocket is supported by your Browser!");
    }
    else {
        alert("Your Browser does not support WebSocket Technology. Please      update your Browser.");
    }
}
function sendmessage() {
    try {
        var ws = new WebSocket("ws://(ip of other user/")
        }
    catch(err)
        {
        alert("Error with creating the WebSocket")
        }
}
</script>
<a href="javascript:confirm()">Run Ip Connector</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tested the Echo demo on http://websocket.org/echo, and it works fine using Chrome 21. Your other example seems to be working fine as well. You can check it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/eQzxV/).

Since you're using Chrome 21, you can [use the Chrome Dev Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751495/debugging-websocket-in-google-chrome#10524936) to see if the WebSocket handshake is going through and whether you see any messages.

Is it possible that you're sitting behind a router/firewall that cuts off the traffic? Can you try WSS on websocket.org? (Enter wss://echo.websocket.org in the Location field.)

Comment: I looked in Chrome Developer tools console window and it didn't seem to be blocking it (it reported a success). It's most likely my firewall. I'll try again on my home network.

Comment: Yeah it seemed to be the firewall/router cutting the traffic. Thanks.