# How to view Web socket response in browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, websocket, google-chrome-devtools

I am using Google Chrome version 24

I am viewing a website where the data is being fetched to the front end by websocket call.

My question is, "Is it possible to view the web socket response from the browser?" Are there any such tools?

Please let me know, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this is possible. Look at the `Network` pane in Dev Tools and look for the line that says `Switching Protocols`

The caveat is you need to **close and reload** the detail pane as it does *not* auto-refresh (as of Chrome 25)

Possible duplicate: [Debugging WebSocket in Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751495/debugging-websocket-in-google-chrome) (though definitely dated information, much has changed since those answers were posted)

This is pretty close to 'up-to-date' information as of (2013-03-20) http://codetheory.in/websocket-traffic-inspection-in-chrome-developer-tools/

Comment: By anyway , can we filter out the response ?? IS there any such facility ??

Comment: Fiddler is easier to use for debugging WebSocket. I have recently written an article on CodeProject, which show you how to debug/inspect WebSocket traffic with Fiddler. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/718660/Debug-Inspect-WebSocket-traffic-with-Fiddler

Answer (score 0):

On the Chrome inspector, click the `Network` tab.

[Link](http://blog.kaazing.com/2012/05/09/inspecting-websocket-traffic-with-chrome-developer-tools/)

Comment: Link not useful. no detail on answer