# Can't see SignalR traffic in browser development tools

Tags: javascript, websocket, signalr

I built server and client code that uses SignalR. The website is working perfectly, but I can't see the web traffic in any browser (chrome, IE, Firefox). I know the web traffic is there because the website is working.

Is there a way to view SignalR Traffic in a browser? If not what is the best external tool for viewing SignalR traffic?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Debugging WebSocket in Google Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751495/debugging-websocket-in-google-chrome)

Answer (score 17):

Yes, you can view SignalR traffic in Developer Tools (Tested with Chrome).

1. Open Network Tab.
2. Click on "WS" to filter out all except Web Socket traffic.
3. Refresh Page. You will see something like this that shows you the connection was established.  Note that you will only see this one line as it only shows that the web socket was connected.  Additional traffic is not shown here like you might expect (see below)

[image]

4. Then click on that row, and it will show you the details. Then select the 'Messages' tab.  It will then show the messages that are being sent and received in real time. Click on the message to see the binary information.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Firefox has builtin support since January 2020 https://hacks.mozilla.org/2020/01/firefox-72-our-first-song-of-2020/

Answer (score 1):

you can use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), see this article :

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Using-fiddler-with-signalr