# Blazor Server Method Call & Execution Details

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am following [this Blazor Server Counter Increment example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/build-your-first-blazor-app?view=aspnetcore-3.1#build-components).

The specific code example is below.

I have three questions:

**1 -** Does the call to IncrementCount after the button is clicked happen via SignalR?

**2 -** Does the execution of IncrementCount happen on the Server? (as opposed to in the browser)

**3 -** If it is via SignalR - How can I see "the call" (the request) being made using Chrome Developer tools? I have looked at the Network Tab and cant not see any activity. See the screengrab:

[image]

Code example:

```
@page "/counter"

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p>Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Depends on if you chose Blazor server-side or Blazor webassembly in the wizard

Comment: @Flores thank you, but I am talking about Blazor Server as mentioned in the title of this question and in the body also.

Comment: Then the answer to 1 & 2 is: Yes.

Comment: For the signalr part: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771676/cant-see-signalr-traffic-in-browser-development-tools

Comment: In chrome developer tools under network like you have, there should be a 101 switching protocols to websocket. You made need to reload the page. Click on that record and then near the top select "Messages". "Headers" is selected by default. It's a binary message so you won't get much out of it but you'll at least be able to see the traffic.

Comment: This question has a good answer for question 3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751495/debugging-websocket-in-google-chrome

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using **Blazor Server**

1 - Yes, it happen via SignalR
2 - Yes, it run on the Server
3 - SignalR use a websoket per default, if you want to see Http request in your browser dev tool, [configure SignalR transport to use long pooling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=dotnet#advanced-http-configuration-options)
Or using firefox, you can use [Firefox’s New WebSocket Inspecto](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2019/10/firefoxs-new-websocket-inspector/)

Using **Blazor WASM**

1 - No, it's executed on browser
2 - No, it's executed on browser
3 - No request, but you can [debug using Visual Studio breakpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/debug?view=aspnetcore-3.1) since 3.1-preview4

Comment: For point 3 - i tried adding the following. But it doesnt work, cant see anything in chrome dev tools: ` endpoints.MapBlazorHub(options =>
                {
                    options.Transports =
                        HttpTransportType.WebSockets |
                        HttpTransportType.LongPolling;
                });`    Any other ideas how to see this? Or have i done something wrong?

Comment: remove `HttpTransportType.WebSockets`

Comment: @fourbeatcoder new update for firefox with WebSocket inspector

Answer (score -1):

For part 3, on chrome 100.0.4896.75, just select "Network -> All"[image]