# Socket.io not sending data

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have 2 parts of my app the register, and the index/login, the case is that i want to update every time an user gets registered, that's done the difficult part of this is make that the index shows a query from the begining and not being send by the register. Code:

Index script:

```
<script>
    var socket = io();
    socket.on('registered', function (msg) {
        $('#messages').empty().append(msg).hide().fadeIn(500);
        console.log(msg);
    });
    function message() {
        var mes = document.getElementById('text').value;
        console.log(mes);
        socket.emit('registered', mes);
    }
</script>
```

Index code to get users:

```
global.mysql.query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4", function (err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var msg = "";
        for(var i = 0; i <= rows.length-1; i++) {
            msg += rows[i].username + '<br>';
        }

        global.io.sockets.emit('registered', msg);

    })
```

Code from register:

```
router.post('/register', function(req, res, next) {
    global.mysql.query("INSERT INTO users (id, username) VALUES (?,?)", [null, req.body.user], function () {
        global.mysql.query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4", function(err, rows, fields) {
            if (err) throw err;
            var msg = "";
            for(var i = 0; i <= rows.length-1; i++) {
                msg += rows[i].username + '<br>';
            }
            global.io.sockets.emit('registered', msg);
        })
    });
});
```

I don't know why because it's the same code...

Comment: Unrelated but you really shouldn't be using global variables like that. Instead of making it global just export the mysql and io objects and do like require('./mysql.js') and require('./io.js')

Comment: I know but is only a test project, i come from PHP and i see that it changes a lot, the only thing that i want is that work. Later i'll see how can i get better code :D

Comment: Just making sure you knew :). Have you tried opening up chrome/safari/firefox dev tools and checking to see if the web socket is open and sending any data? And can we see the code where you setup/attach socket.io to your http server?

Comment: How i can do this? Please tell me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751495/debugging-websocket-in-google-chrome

Comment: Also run your app with `DEBUG=* node myapp.js`. It'll give you more debugging info in your console to help you solve the problem (post the results here). See http://socket.io/docs/logging-and-debugging/

Comment: I get this: 
ÿ0{"sid":"UELCWTkQ27-oLS1iAAAC","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":60000}

With two previous bad requests...

Comment: http://pastebin.com/5TBB7wgj This is debugging

Comment: Did you create a user during this? I don't see anywhere that says the socket sent any data

Comment: The index js has to do that no?

Comment: this is the line when i send data:

        global.io.sockets.emit('registered', msg);

Comment: Did you actually create a user though (submit a POST request / form) while running with the debug log enabled?

Comment: No... I don't know im so new in Node.js i'm have 1 day in node... I so confused, forgive me but i'm so bad at fixing

Comment: `router.post('/register')` listens for a POST request. In order for it to be triggered you need create that request (generally with a HTML form or a XHR). For example `<form action="/register" method="POST"><input type="text" name="user" /><input type="submit" value="Register" /></form>`

Comment: Damn it i fixed it XD The solution was put the io.on('connection') into the query callback... So stupid from my part. Sorry for spending your time D:

Comment: No worries, make sure you add that as an answer and accept it so anyone else who has this problem can find it (plus you get a badge for answering your own question!)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it putting the io.on into the router:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile(global.path + '/views/index.html');
    global.mysql.query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4", function (err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var msg = "";
        for(var i = 0; i <= rows.length-1; i++) {
            msg += rows[i].username + '<br>';
        }
        global.io.on('connection', function(socket){
            console.log('a user connected');

            global.io.sockets.emit('registered', msg);

            socket.on('disconnect', function(){
                console.log('user disconnected');
            });
        });

    })
});
```

Hope it can help anyone!