# How to update a Div without hitting an ajax request

Tags: javascript, php

I usually noticed in stackoverflow.com that sometimes I got update in div without showing an request in firebug console

[image]

As you will noticed that there is updated div content while my firbug seems have no console request. I want to know how this type of update is possible in DOM..

[image]

Comment: websockets https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes though

Comment: Dont know if firebug has an equivalent, but you can see this traffic in chrome dev tools: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751495/debugging-websocket-in-google-chrome

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that is with websockits. its realtime data transfer.
you could use nodeJS its a really good server: https://nodejs.org/

But you need to set up a websocket server for useing it. if you want to try https://www.firebase.com have a small free websocket server.