# Why I cannot see network activity in WhatsApp Web?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, protocols, network-monitoring

Why I cannot see network activity in WhatsApp Web? I mean in developer tools (F12), in the Network tab. I tried with both Firefox and Google Chrome.

Comment: Because they're using Websockets. You can find the info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751495/debugging-websocket-in-google-chrome).

Comment: Please share more details. Is this in any way related to programming?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Firefox navigate to web.whatsapp.com. Open developer tools (F12). Go to network tab. Select WS. Refresh the web page. Now you can see the web socket logs.

You won't see network traffic if you open developer tools after initial WS is send.