# WebSocket debugger in Google Chrome is "minimized" when a new message is received by the current WS

Tags: google-chrome, websocket

I am using Google Chrome, developing an AngularJS frontend generated with `yeoman` and served with `grunt`. I am trying to debug an issue happening on a WebSocket, the browser (client) receiving textual JSON messages at a fast pace (no binary data), with the server not expecting any messages from the client.

However I'm encountering an issue with the debugger itself. According to the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/10524936/4506528:

> Every time you send or receive new messages, you have to refresh the
>   main panel by clicking on [the WebSocket resource] entry on the left.

I'd like that to be true, but unfortunately every time I select the WebSocket resource on the left to analyze it, if that WebSocket receives a new message, the viewport switches to the closest other resource above or below it from the left pane.

[image: WebSocket issue illustration]

- This also happens when the network recording is turned off
- This happens on any tab of the WebSocket properties, not just the Frames tab
- This does not happen if we have a WebSocket selected and another opened WebSocket on the same page has received a message (in the screenshot above, `livereload` is a websocket)
- It happens on http://www.websocket.org/echo.html
- I have tried rebooting Google Chrome

At first I suspected that it was like some IDEs and console loggers, I'd have to enable/disable some kind of option like `Scroll Lock` or `Show console when standard error changes`, but I don't see such option on Google Chrome that would cause this.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Did you fix this issue?

Comment: @AnishChandran Not that I remember, but I don't have any easily executable application readily available to check whether this issue still occurs