# Websocket connections with Postman

Tags: postman

I'm using Postman to test an existing REST API. This API calls async functions on the server which return a response over a websocket using StompJS.

Is it possible to connect to the websocket using Postman?

Comment: @NishchitDhanani Heads up, your site is down

Comment: Thanks, @TheEnvironmentalist, Domain changed to 
https://firecamp.io

Comment: This is now possible in Postman - https://blog.postman.com/postman-supports-websocket-apis/

Answer (score 97):

Update:
May 20, 2021, As of version 8.5.0 - Postman supported WebSocket APIs

---

Obsolete (original) answer:

This is not possible as of May 2017. There is a request for this if you want to upvote:
[github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/4009](http://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/4009)

Comment: As of version 8.5.0 -  Postman supports WebSocket APIs. The linked Github issue has now been closed. 

Comment: @DannyDainton Thank you for your information. I will update my answer.

Comment: @DannyDainton how do you can see on postman about send api call that reply not with a res.send but with a socket.emit?

Answer (score 65):

As the previous comment mentioned you can't do this in Postman. however, I found this Chrome app in the web store. It is very simple, but it's working really well with my local web socket connections.

[Smart Websocket Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/smart-websocket-client/omalebghpgejjiaoknljcfmglgbpocdp?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog)

Comment: thanks for the quick solution almost 3 years later why no postman do this?

Comment: Thank you @JoshSommer. Easy simple and tool, what I need.

Answer (score 31):

As of version 8.5.0 - Postman now supports WebSocket requests.

[image: Websockets]

More information can be found here:

https://blog.postman.com/postman-supports-websocket-apis/

Short Level Up video tutorial of the current functionality:

https://youtu.be/H-7EZVj9D-k

Answer (score 29):

It's not possible in Postman yet; But there is a new alternative for Postman, named [Postwoman](https://postwoman.io/). it's open source and supports realtime Websocket and SSE requests.

**Update**

It seems they have rebranded Postwoman to **[Hoppscotch](https://hoppscotch.io/)** and have improved the Websocket support.

Comment: Not usable for requests to `localhost` _yet_

Comment: `127.0.0.1` works for now but local network calls like 192.168.x.x doesn't work.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't allow you to save requests/messages like Postman does

Comment: Thanks! It is useful.

Answer (score 29):

Postman doesn't support it, but [WebSocket King](https://websocketking.com) does.

[image]

Comment: There is also a [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/websocket-king-client/cbcbkhdmedgianpaifchdaddpnmgnknn/related?hl=en) if you fancy that.

Answer (score 13):

I've run into this issue often enough that I finally created my own barebones GUI for testing websockets. It's called Socket Wrench, it supports

- multiple concurrent connections to servers (with all responses and connections displayed in the same view),
- comprehensive message history to enable easy re-use of messages, and
- custom headers for the initial connection request.

It's available for Mac OS X, Windows and Linux and you can get it from [here](https://asleepysamurai.com/articles/socketwrench?ref=stackoverflow/42269075/a).

Comment: Looks like an interesting project. I'm hitting some errors; I'll follow up with a GitHub issue.

Comment: @EmmanuelMahuni Could you please open a [Github issue](https://github.com/asleepysamurai/socketwrench/issues) with steps to reproduce?

Comment: not bad... i like it. wish there was a way to save the output and the json preview is worse than the text preview. the json should be pretty and the rest should be.. well text

Comment: very good project. nice work... needs just a couple improvements

Comment: @ChristianMatthew Please open a [Github issue](https://github.com/asleepysamurai/socketwrench/issues) on the project, I'll look into implementing it soon :)

Answer (score 11):

You can use the tool APIC available here https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/apic-complete-api-solutio/ggnhohnkfcpcanfekomdkjffnfcjnjam. This tool allows you to test websocket which use either StompJS or native Websocket. More info here at [www.apic.app](https://apic.app)

Comment: Great! but It is beta yet. I an waiting for release.

Comment: That myapic.com url appears to have expired and been taken over by an ad squatter. Looks like they currently use https://apic.app/ instead

Comment: @F.Tamy  It seems that it is not beta anymore

Comment: Yes, It is great

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the exact same problem. Had to make a Web Socket call.
I was able to accomplish this using [Advanced Rest Client](https://install.advancedrestclient.com).
I'm using ARC version : 12.1.3

[image]

Comment: No way to customize anything on the WS request though, just an address field!

Comment: I'm stuck with same problem. I need to set custom headers on connect request, but looks like it's impossible for now

Comment: @DubNazar If you're still interested, you could use [Socket Wrench](https://asleepysamurai.com/articles/socketwrench?ref=stackoverflow/42269075)

Answer (score 4):

Postman currently does not support that.

You can use the online tool at: https://www.piesocket.com/websocket-tester

Answer (score 3):

Postman doesn't support websocket. Most of the extension and app I had ever seen were not working properly.

**Solution which I found**

Just login/ open your application in your browser, and open browser console. Then enter your socket event, and press enter.

```
socket.emit("event_name", {"id":"123"}, (res)=>{console.log(res); });
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Socket.io tester](https://electronjs.org/apps/socket-io-tester), this app lets you connect to a socket.io server and subscribe to a certain topic and/or lets you send socket messages to the server

Comment: this is not what the op is looking for at all

Comment: This does not connect on localhost

Answer (score 2):

Use Firecamp , support websocket(Socketio & Ws ) ,Rest, Graphql ,
You can install in your système or use plugin
https://firecamp.io/
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Have not discovered that postman released web sockets function, but in any case i recently wrote my own simple very simple utility with pure js & html (no bootstrap, no npm, no heavy libs), maybe it would be useful for someone: https://github.com/Wissance/wstester