# Is it possible to call a SignalR Hub from Postman

Tags: signalr, postman, asp.net-core-webapi, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I have an ASP .Net Core 2.2 Web API with a SignalR hub. Is it possible to call one of its methods (for example, SendMessageToAll) using Postman? The problem is that I only have the API - no frontend - and I need to test.

I tried putting the URl to my hub in Postman (api.mydomain.com/chatHub) but then I'm not really sure how to structure the body. I know SignalR uses WebSockets preferably, and I don't know if PostMan has WebSocket functionality. I believe SignalR can also do HTTP requests if WebSockets is not available, which is something Postman can do. But what body do I use? And do I use an HTTP GET or POST?

I saw a post where the person was using this body in Postman:

```
{
    "Target": "SendMessageToGroup",
    "Arguments": [
        "groupA",
        "hello from server"
    ]
}
```

So I tried the same, but when I click "Send" on postman, the SendMessageToGroup method of my hub doesn't get triggered.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check Postman > 8.
If you just inject your hub inside a controller then you can use hub's method and call it's public method from http request inside post man.
Or use another app :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59543405/4751073

Comment: This is no longer the correct answer, see above, web sockets are now supported in the tool. circa 2021

Answer (score 19):

**working for me with asp.net core 5 (didn't tested any other versions)**

first of all - need to get connection id by post request

[post request to get connection id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MA6q.png)

then - connect with id that you received

[connection with received id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDI43.png)

after connection - your first message must be
`{"protocol":"json","version":1}`

[first message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fej6t.png)

then - we can use this request format

[new message from postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHhpM.png)

[new message in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbw0p.png)

need to add this specific symbol to each of your websockets requests

[network with js client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pA02m.png)

when specific symbol is not added - requests does not pass

[when specific symbol is not added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lqhc.png)

Comment: While the top scored answer is correct, this post helped me with some of the SignalR specific steps necessary in order to connect via Postman.

Comment: What is the [] character?

Comment: @EricAmshukov use Js client to get it. I can not paste it here https://i.stack.imgur.com/pA02m.png

Comment: @EricAmshukov it should be this one , record separator, U+001E 30 036 Record Separator RS.. But alt+30 does not work on my computer (gets ▲).. I am not sure why. E.g. Console.WriteLine('\u001E'); and C&P does.

Comment: {"protocol":"json","version":1}
The special box at the end is critical here is a link to one that you can copy into the postman message: https://unicodeplus.com/U+001E  This should be added to the answer.

Answer (score 17):

Now is possible with Postman version > 8.0 using WebSocket Request block.
You can grab the information in their blog post https://blog.postman.com/postman-supports-websocket-apis/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It'd be nice if you could some example code.

Comment: I edited my answer with the link to their blog post in order to not be redundant

Comment: CLARIFICATION: This blog post says it's support *8.5* and above: https://blog.postman.com/postman-supports-websocket-apis/