# How can I call a SignalR Hub via Postman?

Tags: asp.net-core, websocket, postman, asp.net-core-signalr

I know it seems a duplicate question from this thread [Is it possible to call a SignalR Hub from Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56474386/is-it-possible-to-call-a-signalr-hub-from-postman), but I already know that it is possible, after Postman version > 8.0 using WebSocket Request block. But I can not find any good example of how to do it.

I can connect to my hub via Postman, just by passing the hub Url like this:

[image]

But I don't know how can I call the hub method and pass the parameters. Currently, my client program.cs code calls

```
await hubConnection.InvokeAsync("GetTrades", _username);
```

and my connection.On:

```
hubConnection.On<Trade>("ReceiveTrades", (trade) =>
{
    var tradeAsJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(trade);
    Console.WriteLine($"Trade received: {tradeAsJson}");
});
```

How it would be to represent this calls from postman?

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: I did not, sorry

Answer (score 0):

I [create a sample project with signalR](https://github.com/Jason446620/Signalrdemo), you can download it from github. We can open site with https://localhost:44381.

*Tips: please replace SignalR_ConnectionString in `appsettings.json`.*

[image]

And if we want connect to signalR hub, we can use postman, you can follow the steps like below picture.

[image]

[image]

*use `wss://localhost:44381/chatHub`.*

[image]

[image]

Comment: But how can you call your server method? That's the point. I can also connect to my hub, but I can not call my method "GetTrades", passing a username (string) as a parameter

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/SignalR/docs/specs/HubProtocol.md#json-encoding

Answer (score 0):

After establishing the connection put this object in the "Message" area and hit send:

```
{"arguments":["username", "token"],"invocationId":"0","target":"Your Method","type":1}
```

- **arguments**: include all your parameters here.
- **target**: put the method name you want to call