# How to call SignalR event from Postman?

Tags: postman, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I want to call a SignalR event from Postman, I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56474386/is-it-possible-to-call-a-signalr-hub-from-postman) question as well, But it's not helping me.

It's giving the below error, I have mentioned the URL as myUrl due to security reasons in this example.

[image]

Below is the C# equivalent code for the same.

```
private HubConnection hub connection;
private IHubProxy hubProxy;

hubConnection = new HubConnection(myUrl, useDefaultUrl: false);
hubConnection.TransportConnectTimeout = new TimeSpan(10000);
hubConnection.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
hubConnection.Closed += _hubConnection_Closed;
hubConnection.Error += _hubConnection_Error;

hubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy(myHubName);
hubProxy.On<CurrencyPair>("getItems", value =>
{
    DoSomething(value);
}
```

**Postman version** 9.31.9

Answer (score 1):

If you are debugging locally with a SignalR service accessible via an ASP.NET application, it should work with the urls :

- wss://localhost:sslport/myHub (with SSL)
- ws://localhost:port/myHub (without SSL)

where *myHub* is the name you used to map your server-side Hub in `routes.MapHub`.