# where to include credentials to connect to a websocket server in postman?

Tags: sockets, websocket, server, socket.io, serversocket

How do i connect to a server that uses sockets in postman?  I can't understand where I should include the necessary data for the connection like the password, user, id and the port, I was able to connect to the server using a desktop application supplied with the server, by entering the previous data.

Comment: is this help you? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42269075/websocket-connections-with-postman

Comment: I have already read all thé answers in this question , and no it's not helping , that's not m'y question

Comment: hope to get your answer soon. good luck :)

Comment: @Zero0 did you finally get the answer to this quest? If so please share it here.

Comment: No, i abandoned the project and changed work, so soryy i can't help you