# Capture network access from a javascript web application

Tags: javascript, rest

I have a web application running in my browser. It is third party obfuscated javascript. It connects to the server with SSL and it fetches data and then displays it in the browser. I want to get **programmatic** access to the data, but I cannot figure out how it gets it from the server.

I tried to open Chrome Canary Dev Tools, but it *does not show any network access* (other than loading some html, js code and images). I ran wireshark and it shows lots of network access (all encrypted, so it is useless).  What gives?  This javascript app seems to be able to fetch data in a sneaky way, so that Chrome Dev Tools doesn't show it.

Any advice how I can reverse engineer this?

**EDIT**:  I think that the data is fetched by redirecting to a download link, or perhaps with `window.navigator.msSaveBlob`. Anyway, I found it using postman.

Comment: Doubt it is sneaky, probably websocket which you included as a tag....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751495/debugging-websocket-in-google-chrome

Comment: I think it is not using websocket, because if it were, then the handshake will show up in Canary.  I don't see any handshake in Canary.

Comment: If it is not websockets then there are two possibilities. Either the data is included in the first page download. This can be done by encoding the data in a javascript element in the main html page. Or the page is making subsequent http requests. You just have to look in the network tab.

Comment: What web application is this?

Comment: @Thebluefish hmm, i'd rather not say :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to [capture the API call using POSTMAN](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/sending_api_requests/capturing_http_requests) (native Win 6.0.9).  I enabled a Proxy on port 5555, and then click the button to trigger the action in the web app.

Because the web is using SSL, I get an error "Your connection is not private".  However, I can click Advanced / Continue and call the API anyway, which gets captured by POSTMAN.

Advice: In postman, capture to a new folder (called Proxy data). Try it first using a non-SSL site, such as [this one](http://www.stealmylogin.com/).