# How can I find the information sent from the laravel websocket web server?

Tags: php, laravel, events, websocket

I use the websocket  server to send the information of an event as a broadcast.
But I can not get information through laravel echo .
this is my config for laravel and websocket server.

broadcasting config

```
    'pusher' => [
        'driver' => 'pusher',
        'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
        'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
            // 'encrypted' => true,
            'host' => '127.0.0.1',
            'port' => 6001,
            'scheme' => 'http',
            //disable cros orgin
            'useTLS' => false,
        ],
    ],
```

websockets config

```
 'apps' => [
    [
        'id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        'name' => env('APP_NAME'),
        'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
        'path' => env('PUSHER_APP_PATH'),
        'capacity' => null,
        'enable_client_messages' => false,
        'enable_statistics' => true,
    ],
],
```

env config

```
PUSHER_APP_ID=your-pusher-app-id
PUSHER_APP_KEY=your-pusher-key
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=your-pusher-secret
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1
LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_PORT=6001
```

> boostrap.js

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
broadcaster: 'pusher',
key: "your-pusher-key",
cluster: "mt1",
wsHost: window.location.hostname,
wsPort: 6001,

//two config above disable crose orgin
disableStats: true,
forceTLS: false,
```

});

> My event file

```
class OrderStatusChange implements ShouldBroadcast{ 

use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

public $message;
public $user;

public function __construct($message,$user)
{
   $this->message = $message;
   $this->user = $user;
}


public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new Channel('notifications');
}
```

}

> and laravel-echo

```
 window.Echo.channel('notifications').listen('OrderStatusChange', (e) => {
console.log(e.data);
console.log(e);
console.log('window');
```

});

> and console da

```
Pusher :  : ["State changed","initialized -> connecting"] app.js:38851:32
```

Pusher :  : ["Connecting",{"transport":"ws","url":"ws://shop.local:6001/app/your-pusher-key?protocol=7&client=js&version=7.0.2&flash=false"}] app.js:38851:32
Pusher :  : ["State changed","connecting -> connected with new socket ID 307045135.646205772"] app.js:38851:32
Pusher :  : ["Event sent",{"event":"pusher:subscribe","data":{"auth":"","channel":"order"}}]
Pusher :  : ["Event recd",{"event":"pusher_internal:subscription_succeeded","channel":"order"}] app.js:38851:32
Pusher :  : ["No callbacks on order for pusher:subscription_succeeded"]

Comment: you need to check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751495/debugging-websocket-in-google-chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone
i found solution used wrote the answer maybe help someone
Just run the **queue** and If you do not need queues only in the **env** file
Change the value of **QUEUE_CONNECTION** to **sync**
And also use the **ShouldBroadcastNow** value in the event class

Answer (score 0):

do you use `broadcastWith` function in your `event`?

in this function, you can define the data that you want to broadcast.
besides, make sure that your WebSocket is successfully connected.

Comment: The connection has been successfully connected .  and I can send and receive information through the web socket panel, but I can not send and receive information to the event myself.