# Websocket close msg is not shown in chrome's developer tool?

Tags: websocket, google-chrome-devtools

When debugging `websocket` messages, in `chrome developer tool`.

I can see normal data messages (similar as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32753874)). But after close the connection (e.g normally), can't see the `close` msg, *(though I did saw & print the msg via `onclose` handlers in client program)*.

Thus seems control msg is not show?

So, is there anyway to see `close` msg *(and optionally `ping`/`pong` msg)* in `chrome developer tool`?
Or I must use tools like `wireshake` or `postman`?