# Chrome Web Inspector Web Socket Debugging

Tags: google-chrome, websocket, google-chrome-devtools

I can use the Network tab in the **Google Chrome Web Inspector** to debug the network traffic (AJAX requests, etc.). I can check what data is transferred easily. But **Websocket** connections only show as

```
Request URL:ws://localhost/...
Request Method:GET
Status Code:101 Switching Protocols
...
```

and I can't see the transferred data. Is there any build in feature in Google Chrome to inspect the transferred data? Or do I need to use Wireshark?

PS: I'm using the latest stable version (16.0.912.75). If a newer version (beta/dev) has this features, it would be nice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Debugging WebSocket in Google Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751495/debugging-websocket-in-google-chrome)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Chrome and Chromium now have WebSocket message frame inspection. Here are the steps to test it quickly:

1. Navigate to the [WebSocket Echo demo](http://www.websocket.org/echo.html), hosted on the [websocket.org](http://www.websocket.org) site.
2. Turn on the Chrome Developer Tools.
3. Click **Network**, enable **filter** (3rd icon from the left on the top of Dev Tools) to filter the traffic shown by the Developer Tools, and click **WebSockets**.
4. In the Echo demo, click **Connect**. On the Headers tab in Google Dev Tool you can inspect the WebSocket handshake.
5. Click the **Send** button in the Echo demo.
6. To see the WebSocket frames in Chrome Developer Tools, under Name, click the entry representing your WebSocket connection. This refreshes the main panel on the right and makes the WebSocket Frames tab show up with the actual WebSocket message content.

I also posted the [steps with screen shots and video](http://blog.kaazing.com/2012/05/09/inspecting-websocket-traffic-with-chrome-developer-tools/).
[image]

Comment: Be careful when posting copy and paste boilerplate/verbatim answers to multiple questions, these tend to be flagged as "spammy" by the community. If you're doing this then it usually means the questions are duplicates so flag them as such instead.

Comment: Thank you, Kev. BTW, does it apply to comments too... ;-)

Comment: I think Fiddler is easier to use for debugging WebSocket. I have recently written an article on CodeProject, which show you how to debug/inspect WebSocket traffic with Fiddler. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/718660/Debug-Inspect-WebSocket-traffic-with-Fiddler

Comment: The chrome dev tools don't have a "Websocket Frames" tab here anymore :/  There is a "Frames" tab but it is perpetually empty no matter how many websocket messages are sent, or how many times I click on the Name/Path entry on the left.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @nzifntab The WebSockets tab is reachable when enabling filtering, and its Frames tab contains messages.

Comment: @nzifnab It is not empty. you might move [splitter](http://imgur.com/dGP4RrB) in frames tab to see list of frames :

Comment: In Chrome 56 there is a "WS" tab in network filter - that is "WebSockets"

Comment: If your view also only shows the text `Select frame to browse its content.`, it is because you can't see the table of frames above. Try to take the handle for resizing the frame-detail-window which might be right under the headline of the table. This often happens if you switch from a big screen resolution to a smaller one :)

Comment: websocket.org apparently no longer provides the echo demo, so this answer needs to be updated

Answer (score 8):

After some more research I found a duplicate question here: [Debugging WebSocket in Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751495/debugging-websocket-in-google-chrome)

Chrome does't support viewing the traffic in the current stable version. I need to use Wireshark.

Answer (score 0):

Another Idea, for simple web socket testing and lightweight, use Chrome plugin "Simple Web-socket. I wanted to check only if the connection can be establish or not. Following Chrome plugin "Simple Web-socket (link : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simple-websocket-client/pfdhoblngboilpfeibdedpjgfnlcodoo?hl=en)" work like charm. See image.

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/bEHoKg3ijfjaE8-RWTONDBZolc3tP2mLbyWanolCfLmpTHUyYPMSD5I4hKBfi81D2hVpVH_BfQ=w640-h400-e365