# Automatically update websocket frame in chrome web inspector

Tags: google-chrome, websocket

When I inspect a web socket in Google Chrome Web Inspector, (see [Chrome Web Inspector Web Socket Debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8952773/chrome-web-inspector-web-socket-debugging)), I have to keep clicking the socket on the left to refresh the messages on the right.

Is there any way to have this automatically refreshed each time a new message is sent/received? Or has this simply not been developed yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately this is still the case even in dev channel (`v27` atm) and looking at Chromium bugtracker it doesn't seem to be planned either.

[Relevant issue here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=142280&q=websocket%20refresh&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary)

You can vote on it, though I cannot say if that actually accomplishes anything.

Comment: Fiddler supports automatically update websocket frames. I have recently written an article on CodeProject, which show you how to debug/inspect WebSocket traffic with Fiddler. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/718660/Debug-Inspect-WebSocket-traffic-with-Fiddler

Answer (score 0):

I have tested with latest Chrome (32.0.1700), they still don't support automatically update of WebSocket frames. However you can use Fiddler (with FiddlerScript) to inspect WebSocket traffic in the same way you inspect HTTP traffic, and it supports auto refresh of frames.

[image: Inspect WebSocket Traffic]

Please refer to the article on CodeProject, which show you how to Debug/Inspect WebSocket traffic with Fiddler (with FiddlerScript). http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/718660/Debug-Inspect-WebSocket-traffic-with-Fiddler