# In Meteor Collections, use an array-field or another collection?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, collections, meteor, field

**The question**

In short, my question is: when an array in a document is changed, will the users receive the new array, or just the changes?

If that question is unclear, I've described my problem below.

**The problem**

I have a collection whose documents contain an array field two users will push values to. A document in this collection kind of looks like this:

```js
var document = {
    userId1: "...user id...", // The id of the first of the two users.
    userId2: "...user id...", // The id of the second of the two users.
    data: [] // The field the two users will push values to.
}
```

`data` will from the beginning be empty, and the users will then take turns pushing values to it.

When one of the user pushes some value to `data`, the server will send the changes to the second user. Will the second user receive the entire `data`-array, or just the changes (the pushed value)? I'm a little bit worried that the second user will receive the entire `data`-array, even though it's just a single value that's been pushed to it, and if `data` contains many values, I fear this will become a bottleneck.

Is this the case? If it is, using another collection for storing the values will solve it, right? Something like this:

```js
var document = {
    id: "...unique id...",
    userId1: "...user id...", // The id of the first of the two users.
    userId2: "...user id..." // The id of the second of the two users.
}

var documentData = {
    idReference: "...the unique id in the document above...", 
    value: "...a value..."
}
```

Instead of pushing the values into an array in `document`, insert them into a collection containing `documentData`. This (I know) won't have the downside I fear the first solution has (but I rather use the first solution if it doesn't have the downside).

Comment: You can double check exactly what comes down wire by following [these instructions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8952773/chrome-web-inspector-web-socket-debugging) to view frames in the websocket connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/livedata/DDP.md

> - `changed` (server -> client):
>
>   - `collection`: `string` (collection name)
>   - `id`: `string` (document ID)
>   - `fields`: optional object with EJSON values
>   - `cleared`: optional array of strings (field names to delete)

Users will receive the new array. To only send "diffs," use a collection of `{userId: userId, value: value}` documents.

Answer (score 0):

I inspected what was sent as commented by user728291, and it seems like the entire array-field is sent, and not just the pushed value. I don't know if this always is the case (I just tested with an array containing few and small values; if it contains many or big values Meteor maybe try to do some optimization I couldn't see in my tiny test), but I'll go with the solution using another collection instead of the array-field.