# How much data does meteor push to clients when a collection is modified?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I'm interested in the bandwidth usage aspect of meteor. When a collection is modified, do clients receive the entire updated collection or just the field(s) that were changed (or some kind of delta/diff data)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just the changed field values that are sent over the wire. If you want, you can see it for yourself by following [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8952773/chrome-web-inspector-web-socket-debugging).

Answer (score 0):

It also depend on your subscriptions as well.  If you didn't subscribe the field you updated.  It will not be send down to the client.  You should really look into 'merge box' to understand this better.

I think Chris from eventedmind did videos on this topic before.

Here are links:
 https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/meteor-liveresultsset
 https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/meteor-livedatasession