# not able to see socket.io request logs in firebug

Tags: javascript, sockets, socket.io, firebug

I am using **[socket.io](http://socket.io)**

Like when there is normal **http request** we get to see **LOGS** in **firebug**

But in socket.io i am not able to see **LOGS** in **firebug**

Is there any way to see this logs Or I am missing something ?

[socket.io demo](http://socket.io/demos/chat/)

Comment: Use something like Wireshark? Or google "debug websocket"

Comment: @RobIII i searched and came to know that **socket.io internally uses web sockets** and got this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8952773/chrome-web-inspector-web-socket-debugging) can you post this as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about firebug (there seems to be [an extension](https://github.com/firebug/websocket-monitor)) but [Chrome (apparently) supports this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10525328/215042).
You could also try / resort to tools like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and/or [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler).

Key here is that socket.io is basically ([usually](https://github.com/socketio/engine.io#transports)) just websockets.

Answer (score 0):

Firebug does not support inspection of WebSocket communication, but there is an [enhancement request](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/issues/6452) for this.
Though as Firebug is obviously discontinued, you may rather have a look at the [enhancement request for the Firefox DevTools](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=927481).

There is also an extension called [WebSocket monitor](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/websocket-monitor/) (written by the main contributor of Firebug), which adds a WebSocket inspection panel to the DevTools.